# "Они кормили его мясом своих собак" — сколько смыслов имеет фраза?

Tags: смысл, грамотная-речь, многозначность

В одном из пособий по культуре речи приведена в качестве примера двусмысленности фраза: **Они кормили его мясом своих собак**.

При этом сказано, что предложение это можно понимать  в четырех смыслах.
Я смог отыскать только три...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смыслов не меньше пяти (четыре названы): есть два заметно различающихся варианта кормления собак "евонным мясом". Это может быть мясо, которое он принёс, или мясо с его (надо надеяться, кабана какого-нибудь) собственных костей.

Comment: Рекордная глубина!

Answer (score 2):

**Могли кормить собак:**

*евонным* мясом;

мясом, предназначавшимся ему.

**Могли кормить его:**

собачьим мясом;

мясом, предназначавшимся собакам.